# Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://localhost:5005/.well-known/openid-configuration' on dockerising the project

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, microservices, identityserver4

I have created a microservice on .Net Core 3.1. I have used Identityserver4 as IDPClient. The project is working fine locally. After dockerising the project(Docker-compose), and calling the Identityserver from MVC Client application it is throwing **Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://localhost:5005/.well-known/openid-configuration'**

MVC Application Startup code

```
 services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
            .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://localhost:5005/";
                options.ClientId = "taxationclient_presentation";
                options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                options.ResponseType = "code";
                options.Scope.Add("openid");
                options.Scope.Add("profile");
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
            });
```

Comment: It is good if you share docker-compose file.

Answer (score 0):

For it to work, you first need to make sure that there is a valid HTTPS TLS certificate for Localhost inside the container. Second, are you sure the application is actually listening on port 5001 or is it 443? You usually have 5001 locally in visual studio, but in production it changes to port 443.

Comment: I have verified that application is actually listening on port 5001 but there is no valid HTTPS TLS certificate for Localhost inside the container. Can you share some links which can help to do it?

Comment: the best would be to create a real certificate that all browsers and clients can trust, perhaps using letsencrypt. A localhost cert is mainly used for development.